# How do you store variables fields?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I've a database where I've comments, votes, galleries, images, etc...
For examples, galleries and images can be commented using the same form, then I'll store it in a single table, comment.

I'm wondering how would store this type information in the comment table?
Using a ENUM type, a foreign key against a type table, hardcoded on insert, etc.. ?

Comment: IF the comment would be related to a parent record would you really need to know the type at the comment level?

Comment: @Roadie57: Personally, I'd still want to know at the comment level. It would make answering questions like "How many comments have we received on all galleries?" much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign key against a type table would get my vote. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice!  Yeah that's what I was getting at with Option #3.  The CommentType is definitely optional at that point it seems; I don't think it really provides much query support at that point.  Unless you're thinking the comment type is disjoint from gallery/image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so that means if I need to add a new resource I need to add a new intersection table referencing both the resource and the comments is it worth to maintain ?

Comment: @John: Based on the limited information available, here's another thought. If there is some commonality between items like gallery and image, perhaps you could create a master "Resource" table and a single intersection to the comments based off that master. You might then create "Gallery" and "Image" as child tables off of the master "Resource" to hold attributes that are unique to each type.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a couple of ways you could design this while retaining foreign keys.

The first is to basically have a comment table for each type; keep them separate.  For each comment have a foreign key to the parent gallery or image, depending on the table.

The second is to have a table (say commentables) that contains common data for anything that is commentable.  Each gallery or image has a foreign key to a unique corresponding row in commentables.  Each row in the comment table has a foreign key to the commentable, along with the text of the comment, date, etc.

You'll probably find this useful anyway since you'll eventually want metadata for the *collection* of comments as a whole...e.g. to specify whether commenting is disabled, enabled for friends only, or enabled for everybody.

**Edit** Option 3 is like option 1 but instead of having full separate comment tables for each commentable type, just have separate *associative* tables for each commentable type.

```
|comments|    |gallery_comments|   |image_comments |
 --------      ----------------     ---------------
|id  (pk)|    |comment_id  (fk)|   |comment_id (fk)|
|text    |    |gallery_id  (fk)|   |image_id   (fk)|
|date    |     ----------------     ---------------
|author  |
 --------
```

Much better than option 1 in my opinion.